# SwiftKey keyboard and SpannableStringBuilder with end space character issue

Tags: java, android

I have the strange problem when using SwiftKey Keyboard if I passed a string from `EditText` to `SpannableStringBuilder` and set it back to `EditText`; any Space character at the end will be trimmed automatically, using default keyboard this not happen here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {
    EditText txtEntry;
    boolean IsChanged = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEntry);
        txtEntry.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (IsChanged)
            return;

        IsChanged = true;


        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        sb.append(txtEntry.getText());


        txtEntry.setText(sb);
        txtEntry.setSelection(txtEntry.getText().length());

        IsChanged = false;
    }
}
```

I m doing this as I,m adding dynamic emotions to `EditText`, but can't add spaces so I made a very simple code to discover the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i fixed the problem, first of all must add inputType="textNoSuggestions" to EditText; this will prevent firing OnTextChanged Event twice, second the processing of string should be throw Editable; not throw EditText itself

Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{

    EditText txtEntry;
    boolean IsChanged = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEntry);
        txtEntry.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        txtEntry.addTextChangedListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String ss = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if (IsChanged)
            return;
        IsChanged = true;

        String sInput =editable.toString().replace(" ","@space@");

        SpannableStringBuilder ObjBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        ObjBuilder.append(sInput);

        while (true)
        {
            int iStartIndex = sInput.indexOf("@space@");
            int iEndIndex = iStartIndex + "@space@".length();

            if (iStartIndex == -1)
                break;
            sInput = sInput.replaceFirst("@space@","[space]");
            Drawable ObjDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.space);
            ObjDraw.setBounds(0,0,10,60);
            ImageSpan Image = new ImageSpan(ObjDraw);
            ObjBuilder.setSpan(Image,iStartIndex,iEndIndex,0);
        }

        editable.clear();
        editable.append( ObjBuilder);
        txtEntry.setSelection(txtEntry.getText().length());


        IsChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case it is not only space but _all_ characters that are not letters or numbers. Changing from `onTextChanged` to `afterTextChanged` made no difference (`editable.toString()` was still missing the space) but luckily I needed to disable predictions in the problematic field, so `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);` helped. The bug seems to be connected to the prediction: if you enter the space or other symbol by pasting, it stops the prediction and then SwiftKey types spaces normally.